# My users get "net::err_name_not_resolved"

Tags: android, dns, github-pages, nslookup, dig

I did get messages from android phone users that my website is not loading.

When an android phone clicks on a link to go to my website it gets the error: `net::err_name_not_resolved`

On computers and iPhones, I don't get the error.
When the android user copies the link and pastes it into the browser the website loads correctly.

Link to my website:
https://www.losangelestorrevieja.com

I have custom resource records from google:

- Name: *
- type:CNAME
- Info:www.losangelestorrevieja.com.

.

- Name: wwww
- type:CNAME
- Info:enzotrompeneers.github.io.

if I nslookup www.losangelestorrevieja.com I don't receive an IP address

Answer (score 1):

I think it's already solved, i tried nslookup'ing and acessing with my Android phone, both worked.

Depending on DNS Server, it may take some time to update. Maybe this was your problem, the reflection isn't instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

The `www` domain itself resolves: [www.losangelestorrevieja.com](https://www.losangelestorrevieja.com).

But the SSL certificate does not cover: [losangelestorrevieja.com](https://losangelestorrevieja.com).

[SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=losangelestorrevieja.com) says:

> Certificate not valid for domain name

---

`$ dig losangelestorrevieja.com. a`

```
losangelestorrevieja.com. 300   IN  A   185.199.111.153
losangelestorrevieja.com. 300   IN  A   185.199.108.153
losangelestorrevieja.com. 300   IN  A   185.199.109.153
losangelestorrevieja.com. 300   IN  A   185.199.110.153
```

`$ dig www.losangelestorrevieja.com. a`

```
www.losangelestorrevieja.com. 55 IN CNAME   enzotrompeneers.github.io.
enzotrompeneers.github.io. 2978 IN  A   185.199.108.153
enzotrompeneers.github.io. 2978 IN  A   185.199.109.153
enzotrompeneers.github.io. 2978 IN  A   185.199.110.153
enzotrompeneers.github.io. 2978 IN  A   185.199.111.153
```

`$ dig enzotrompeneers.github.io. a`

```
enzotrompeneers.github.io. 3180 IN  A   185.199.110.153
enzotrompeneers.github.io. 3180 IN  A   185.199.111.153
enzotrompeneers.github.io. 3180 IN  A   185.199.108.153
enzotrompeneers.github.io. 3180 IN  A   185.199.109.153
```

`$ dig www.enzotrompeneers.github.io. a`

```
www.enzotrompeneers.github.io. 3600 IN  A   185.199.111.153
www.enzotrompeneers.github.io. 3600 IN  A   185.199.108.153
www.enzotrompeneers.github.io. 3600 IN  A   185.199.109.153
www.enzotrompeneers.github.io. 3600 IN  A   185.199.110.153
```

`$ nslookup www.losangelestorrevieja.com`

```
Non-authoritative answer:
www.losangelestorrevieja.com    canonical name = enzotrompeneers.github.io.
Name:   enzotrompeneers.github.io
Address: 185.199.109.153
Name:   enzotrompeneers.github.io
Address: 185.199.110.153
Name:   enzotrompeneers.github.io
Address: 185.199.111.153
Name:   enzotrompeneers.github.io
Address: 185.199.108.153
```

Requesting from Google DNS servers `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4` might have the DNS updates from Cloud DNS eg. `ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com` the soonest. It generally can take up to 24 hours until it can be resolved by any DNS server (even if in most cases, this happens rather instantly). Even when using a DSL router, one can change the default (ISP provider assigned) DNS server to any other DNS server (in case it not updates from Cloud DNS too soon).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was DNS propagation issue and it's now resolving, it may take up to 48 hours for some nameservers to catch new changes

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/losangelestorrevieja.com

https://ns1.com/resources/dns-propagation